# Google Test/Mock test fail if expected call is over-saturated

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest, googlemock

How can I make google test fail if google mocked method is called more than expected times?

Here is the example:

```
class MockIO : iIO
{
    MOCK_METHOD1(IO_Read, void (uint8_t));
};

TEST(case, test)
{
    MockIO io;
    EXPECT_CALL(io, IO_Read(0x01)).Times(10);
    for (i=0; i<20; i++)
        io.IO_Read(0x01);
}
```

As I understand I should try

```
EXPECT_CALL(io, IO_Read(0x01)).Times(10).Throw(exception);
```

But in embedded projects exceptions not used.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should use strict mocks for your test.

```
TEST(case, test){
StrictMock<MockIO> io;
EXPECT_CALL(io, IO_Read(0x01)).Times(10);
```

When using a Strictmock, not expected calls cause a testfailure.

http://code.google.com/p/googlemock/wiki/CookBook#Nice_Mocks_and_Strict_Mocks

Answer (score 1):

> But in embedded projects exceptions not used.

It doesn't matter, because you should not build your unit test to be run on the embedded platform, but for your PC.

Setting the expectations can be reduced to this :

```
EXPECT_CALL(io, IO_Read(0x01)).Times( AtLeast( 10 ) );
```

Failing to satisfy the condition is going to throw an exception.

To enable googlemock library to throw exceptions on failed expectations :

```
::testing::GTEST_FLAG(throw_on_failure) = true;
```